# Getting an error when trying to read json file via fetch

Tags: json, file, vue.js, electron

I am trying to read `json` file from local, but as a response I am getting an error look like this

```
Fetch API cannot load file:///var/www/desktop-electron//dashboard/bnb.json. URL scheme "file" is not supported
```

Here is my code

```
fetch(`${drr}/dashboard/bnb.json`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                this.currency = res;

                Object.assign(this.stock, res.pairs[0]);
                Object.assign(this.header, res.pairs[0]);
                this.header.name = res.name;
            }).catch(function(e) { console.log(e) });
```

I have read all solutions which from google ,but can not solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to omit the "file://" scheme altogether?
Also first try to wrap the URI in a Request Object, like described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch)

```
fetch(new Request(URI))
```

Answer (score 0):

Native fetch (Chromium) doesn't support to load resources from local via file protocol. In short you can't, you need to use other way around (like fs.readfile, or some other means) or host json to remote endpoint to use fetch.